# How to setup git and git-sync in a docker container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to setup up git and git-sync in my new docker container but I am not sure how to do that or if that is the right way to do it? If there is a easier way to do it for example I also use kubernetes and I am trying to see what kubernetes can do as far as git-sync is concerned. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need it? It doesn't seem to be a good idea, especially with Docker. Usually you should to create new Docker image(:tag) per release, which will be used by Kubernetes.

Comment: Not sure what is the standard industry practice?

Comment: Hi user1870400. Jan garaj gave the current best way to release your dockerized app ;)

Comment: But I have some setup scripts under my repo that needs to be run to setup the environment and things like gradle build under my repo to produce the jar file prior to running my application (the jar executable)

Answer (score 0):

Don't treat Docker container as a VM. Usually you shouldn't go to the container to run commands or to set up settings. Use `docker build` to build all what do you need (jar file, JVM server, ....) from Dockerfile and use environment variable to handle any settings (or volume with setting file). Your container image entrypoint (cmd) can be some your script (bootstrap.sh), which can handle also some start activities. Generally: your container should be stateless. For versioning use tags. Take your time and read some doc and some real Docker app examples. You will see there what is the best practice.